# How to display available branches in Android source tree?

Tags: git, android, android-ndk, repository

Following directions on Android's main website to pull down sources, I'm looking at this command to initialize repo for the cupcake branch:

`repo init -u git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git -b cupcake`

How can I view all available branches besides cupcake, i.e eclair, donut, etc...?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible using the "repo" script, but you can query the list of available branches using git:

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest.git
$ cd manifest
$ git branch -r
```

If you don't want to clone the repository just for this, you can see the branches on the [web interface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest).

Comment: [Git web interface](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/manifest.git;a=heads) for the people who don't want to clone the git repository just to see what branches are available.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Your link seems to be broken. Here's the new link: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest

Comment: @gsingh2011: thanks! Now I have the reputation required to mention the location in the answer, so that comments don't pile up on every change.

Answer (score 34):

The quickest way to list available branches without cloning/downloading anything is this one-liner:

```
$ git ls-remote -h https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest.git
```

Answer (score 18):

The manifests are already checked out as part of the repo init process. To get a list of available branches,
(from your android repo checkout root), use this command:

```
git --git-dir .repo/manifests/.git/ branch -a
```

Comment: It seems that the location of manifests git location has changed:

"git --git-dir .repo/manifests.git/ branch -a"

Answer (score 6):

See list of "Codenames, Tags, and Build Numbers" at http://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

git access is refused

Answer (score 3):

For the repository you have perform `repo sync`. You can find them in your local directory `.repo/manifests`. Suppose you check `aosp` to `～/aosp`.

```
$ cd ~/aosp/.repo/manifests
$ git branch -r
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming at the top of an AOSP tree, a list of tags can be shown either,

`$ git --git-dir .repo/manifests.git tag -l`

or

`$ (cd .repo/manifests; git tag -l; )`