# git-repo how to list all branches in one google repo?

Tags: git-repo

is there any way to list all branches in google `repo`?

I found it is very difficult to understand `repo`. [Here](https://source.android.com/source/using-repo.html) only provide very few commands which does not not provide a list branch mechanism.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display available branches in Android source tree?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874347/how-to-display-available-branches-in-android-source-tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Patrick Tsai
`git --git-dir .repo/manifests.git/ branch -a`

Comment: This lists all the branches of the manifest itself, not all the branches in all the git repositories listed in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

is `git branch` not what you are looking for?

This lists all branches, e.g.:

```
branch_name_1
branch_name_2
*master
```

**Note:** The `*` preceding a branch name denotes the current branch.

To switch branches use: `git checkout branch_name_#`

Comment: git-repo is a google tool. A single google repo contains lots of git projects (hundreds!). So it will be very annoying to check the branches for projects one by one. The repo root only contains `.repo`. So it is not git tracked I think. I think the `repo` will have a "repo-branch" so it can make sure each project on the correct branches and versions. That means if I change the single sub-project branch it will mess up the repo.

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874347/how-to-display-available-branches-in-android-source-tree

Comment: Thanks for point me to another post. But your answer is wrong for git-repo. It is rather a general git instruction, which I am very familiar with. And you cannot just git checkout. `git branch` also does not work normally for git-repo because the actual .git info in located in different dirs. The accept answer in another post cannot list all available branches either.